# How to subtract a value typed into one cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create an "Inventory Chart".

The actual chart contains more information, but these are the important ones.

|  | A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Item | Stock |  | Item | Withdrawel |
| 2 | Item 1 | 32 |  | Item 4 | 5 |
| 3 | Item 2 | 228 |  | Item 3 | 20 |
| 4 | Item 3 | 121 |  | Item 1 | 10 |
| 5 | Item 4 | 93 |  |  |  |
| 6 | Item 5 | 44 |  |  |  |

- Column A contains the item names
- Column B contains the current stock. It can be modified manually or by VBA
- Column C is a spacer
- Column D is where the user inserts the item he/she withdrew from stock
- Column E is where the user inserts the quantity he/she withdrew
- Columns D and E are meant to go down infinitely, so you have a continuing history of withdrawals

**I'd like that after the user inserts the quantity in column E, it is subtracted from the stock value in column B of the correct item.**

**But since B can also be modified manually (e.g. for Inventory) I can't use a formula here.**

---

**EDIT:**
Here is the actual chart. I'll still use "Item 1" etc. as item names. The actual item names can contain special characters such as spaces, "-", "/", "(", ")" and "." if that matters.

Please note that in this chart A is another column than before. I always adjusted the code you provided to match the columns.

Column A contains all possible variants of Item Numbers. Empty cells can occur here.

D remains as a spacer.

Columns A, B and C actually go down to line 46 (including the header). Columns E to I go down infinitely. I just didn't want the post to get unnecessarily large, so I shortened it to 6 lines.

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-1wig{font-weight:bold;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-fymr{font-weight:bold;border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-0pky{border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-1wig">Item Number</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">Item</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">Stock</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">Item</th>
    <th class="tg-fymr">Withdrawal</th>
    <th class="tg-1wig">Use</th>
    <th class="tg-1wig">Employee</th>
    <th class="tg-1wig">Date</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">AAA-AAA-0000</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Item 1<br></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">32</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Item 4</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">5</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Usage</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Kuraiko</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">09.09.2018</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">0AA-AAA-0000</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Item 2</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">228</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Item 3</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">20</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Usage</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Kuraiko</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">10.09.2018</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax">AAAA-AAA-0000</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Item 3</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">121</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Item 1</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">10</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Usage</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">Kuraiko</td>
    <td class="tg-0lax">11.09.2018</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Item 4</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">93</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">Item 5</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky">44</td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0pky"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
    <td class="tg-0lax"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you mind if i put a value in column C so that I can check whether the withdrawal was already subtracted? You could change the font to white so that nobody would notice haha

Comment: Are you trying to use native excel-vba, or visual basic? They are two different technologies.

Comment: In your bulletpoints you note that Column `B` is the one to be changed by VBA logic (or user), but in your bold notes at the bottom you reference your blank column `C`. Which is it? It's difficult to understand.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion here with column C. I actually meant B and edited my main post.

@Luuklag Nativ-Excel VBA I guess... But I didn't know that there is a difference. Perhaps that explains why I have so much struggle understanding the use of VB in Excel :/

Comment: Another way would be to lock column B, and add column G and H to account for additions to inventory. Then you can simply make column B the difference between two `Sumif()`'s.

Comment: It will help searching on Google to not search for "VB" but rather "VBA" they are somewhat similar syntax (kind of) but entirely different beasts. VB is a slightly outdated, but pretty robust programming language where VBA is a more outdated (but still in wide wide wide use as there is no real replacement) scripting language for MS Office products.

Comment: I would strongly advise against directly manipulating values in column B, as this will make your changes untraceable. I suggest you adopt @Tedinoz's solution and *add* values to column B by simply "withdrawing" negative amounts. This will document all stock changes in a transparent manner.

Comment: @cars10m Done. I kinda adopted Tedinoz' solution.
I'll add an answer to this post explaining my solution in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being unable to put a formula in column C is a setback, but there's also the risk that the manual adjustment is not accurate.

I suggest creating two new columns. The first = "W/Drawl Total" (let's say this is column F) and the second = "W/Drawal Proof" (say, Column G)

The formula in F2 is this:

```
=SUMIF($D$2:$D$6,A2,$E$2:$E$6)
```

This sums all the withdrawals for the stock item listed on that row.
Note that the "Range" and the "Sum Range" are expressed as absolute terms. This is very important.
In this example, the range is only from row 2 to 6, but in reality, you would edit the row number for the actual bottom row of the range, and copy the formula down by row.

The formula in G2 is this:

```
=+C2-F2
```

Pretty simple. It takes the value in Column C and deducts the "Withdrawals Total". This will highlight where manual data entry does not agree with the transaction data.   You also copy this formula down the column.

Comment: I think this solution delivers a more predictable behaviour than @JNevill's solution, as you can actually correct your input in column `E` cells. If you correct an input in @JNevill's column `E` it will be seen as a new change event and the value will be subracted *again*. The  column `F` could be hidden, if desired ...

Comment: Hello Tedinoz and thanks for your answer.

I think I get your idea. First of all I confused C with B n my main post. Sorry for that, I edited it to be correct.

Comment: And second: after testing around with this solution and adding it into my chart I'll definitely gonna consider to use it. But I wanna see if I can find a VB solution first.

Comment: No worries. I wouldn’t mind using a VBA solution either. But I am worried about the risk of inaccurate manual data entry in column C.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you are after here. You can use a `Worksheet_Change()` event to detect if a value has changed in Column E and do the calculation to update B:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 5 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then  'A cell in Column E was changed
        Dim withdrawal As Long
        Dim item As String

        withdrawal = Target.value
        item = Target.Offset(,-1).value

        Dim foundItem as String
        Set foundItem = Range("A:A").Find(item)

        foundItem.Offset(,1).value = foundItem.Offset(,1).value - withdrawal
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello JNevill and thanks for your answer:

The code works, but not quite as I imagined it.
From my understanding "Target.Offset(, -3).Value" grabs the value from three columns before the target column. So if the target column is 5 then _Target.Offset(, -3)_ grabs the value in Column 2.

The problem with that is, that the Items added by the user in D may not match in line with the items in A. The code would need to check the Item in D first, then find this Item in A and change the appropriate value in B.

I hope you get what I mean -_-

Comment: I see. I thought there was a relationship at the row level between your columns `A:B` and `D:E`. I will edit.

Comment: I have updated my answer to perform a `Range.Find()` for the value in Column A and then update the corresponding value in Column B

Comment: Applying this code I get an error.
"Compiling error: Object required"
Perhaps because it expects an item in each cell of D?

Comment: Which line gives you the error? It wouldn't fail on compile because of the way the sheet is set up (empty item in D). That may cause an error, but not at compile time. Perhaps I fat fingered something in there as I didn't test any of this.

Comment: The very first line gives the error. It gets marked yellow. Also "foundItem =" from line 10 gets marked as if you'd mark it with your mouse for C&P.
The error appears if I change any cell in the sheet.

Comment: But whats the error? Colors don't mean much to me. Are you on a Mac? What version of Excel are.you using?

Comment: `Compiling error: Object required`
That is the error. I'm working on Windows with Excel 2016.

Comment: It all looks good to me. Insure that the code resides in the worksheet's code (not in a separate module).

Answer (score 0):

I started my answer a while ago and got a bit sidetracked. It looks like @JNevill and I had pretty similar ideas!

Basically, if you make a change in the second item column or in the withdrawals column, it will check through your empty column adjacent to it and if there is no `"x"` there it will attempt to subtract that record's withdrawal from the total in the stock column and finally mark `"x"` in the empty column when it is successful.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim colItems1 As String: colItems1 = "B"
    Dim colStock As String: colStock = "C"
    Dim colEmpty As String: colEmpty = "D"
    Dim colItems2 As String: colItems2 = "E"
    Dim colWithdrawal As String: colWithdrawal = "F"

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range(colItems2 & ":" & colWithdrawal)) Is Nothing Then

        Dim rowLast As Long
        rowLast = Range(colWithdrawal & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        'Uncomment this for it to only attempt to subtract when there isn't an "x" in each row
'        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(colEmpty & "2:" & colEmpty & rowLast)) <> rowLast - 1 Then

            Dim vals As Variant
            vals = Range(colEmpty & "2:" & colWithdrawal & rowLast).Value2

            Dim i As Long
            For i = LBound(vals) To UBound(vals)
                If Len(vals(i, 1)) = 0 And Len(vals(i, 2)) > 0 And Len(vals(i, 3)) > 0 Then

                    Dim itemMatch As Range
                    Set itemMatch = Range(colItems1 & ":" & colItems1).Find(vals(i, 2))

                    If Not itemMatch Is Nothing Then
                        itemMatch.Offset(0, 1).Value2 = itemMatch.Offset(0, 1).Value2 - vals(i, 3)
                        Range(colEmpty & 2 + i - 1).Value2 = "x"
                    End If
                End If
            Next i

'        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

If you wanted to hide the new `"x"` markings in your blank column you could hide that whole column or to keep that spacing you could just make the font color white in it.

Comment: That code works... almost.
Though it does exactly what I want, if I choose the second item (Item 2) from line A in D for withdrawal it always subtracts from the stock Item 1. Regardless at which line I wanted to withdraw Item 2.

Comment: Are you testing it on your actual data or just on the example that you gave us above? Because there might be some difference in the real data that i didnt expect causing us issues

Comment: I'm testing it on my actual data.
I'm gonna post the whole chart tomorrow.

Comment: @Kuraiko Just for my sanity could you test it on your machine using the mock data you provided in the question?

Comment: I've tested both variants from your post with the mock data. Nothing happens when filling D and E with data.
If I test the second variant with my actual data it it pretty much does nothing as well, but if I change an Item in D, when there was already an Item entered, it causes Excel to crash completely.

I'll just post the actual chart. I can only think of that being the issue.

Comment: @Kuraiko no wonder my macro didnt work, your actual data has an extra column at the start....... I changed my answer so it's easy to adjust now

Answer (score 0):

Overthinking cars10ms comment to my main post and looking into Tedinoz answer again I came to the following solution now.

- I've put a formula into C: `=SUMIF($E:$E;B2;$F:$F)`
- Next I did was making an inventory by filling E with all the Items we have and F with the current Stock
- Now I'm gonna lock C and some other columns/cells, so the few other users having access to this sheet can't screw up

If I knew beforehand how complicated it can get to use VB in an Excel Sheet, I would've thought of such an easy solution earlier. I just thought it would be easier and more convenient.

Anyway, huge THANKS to everybody for your efforts and time! And sorry that I couldn't apply one of the VB solutions. At least I got a tiny inside into VB and I'm gonna lookup  the difference of VB and VBA now ;)